# In Rapidminer extract hashtags from content

Tags: regex, hashtag, rapidminer

I have some tweets data in a csv file and I want to (1) extract only the hashtags (with special characters like ##cloudcomputing, #cloud_computing, #101Cloud, etc and considering multiple case representation as one hashtag like #edtech, #Edtech, #EdTech,etc), (2) group the tweets based on hashtags and (3) count the number of times each hashtag word occurred in a document or across documents of a corpus. I understand that I have to use regular expressions in the Filter Examples operator on the 'Title' column but don't know how to. 
Some regular expressions I tried to use but which failed are: attribute name (Title) = regular expression
(?i)#.*
^#
/(#\w+)/u
/(#[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-_]*)/ig
Here is the link to the XML code of the process I have created
https://myexplorations.sharefile.com/d-sefddef555cf4d61a 
Here is the link to the source data file
https://myexplorations.sharefile.com/d-s92197963830466cb 
Could someone help please?

Answer (score 1):

Both the files are in XML format, but not in a standard RapidMiner format, one of them looks a bit like MS Word, is that right?

Anyway, feel free to repost the data in a different format, but I think this might help. 
First make sure you have the Text Processing Extension from RapidMiner.

Next use Process Documents from Data and inside it use the following 3 operators: Transform Cases, Cut Document & Combine Documents.  What these do is for each example in your CSV make the text lower case, extract the hashtags individually from the text & then combine them into a new document (in case there are more than one hashtag in a piece of text).
The regEx I used was **(?i)#[0-9a-z_]***, this was just for speed, but it should capture all the cases I could think of.
The output of this process is a wordlist count across the corpus telling you how many times a hashtag occured in a document.  That should get you started.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<process version="7.0.001">
  <context>
    <input/>
    <output/>
    <macros/>
  </context>
  <operator activated="true" class="process" compatibility="7.0.001" expanded="true" name="Process">
    <process expanded="true">
      <operator activated="true" class="read_csv" compatibility="7.0.001" expanded="true" height="68" name="Read CSV" width="90" x="45" y="136">
        <parameter key="csv_file" value="myCSV"/>
        <parameter key="column_separators" value=","/>
        <list key="annotations"/>
        <list key="data_set_meta_data_information">
          <parameter key="0" value="myTextColum.true.text.regular"/>
          <parameter key="1" value="anotherColumn.true.nominal.regular"/>
        </list>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="text:process_document_from_data" compatibility="7.0.000" expanded="true" height="82" name="Process Documents from Data" width="90" x="179" y="85">
        <parameter key="vector_creation" value="Term Occurrences"/>
        <list key="specify_weights"/>
        <process expanded="true">
          <operator activated="true" class="text:transform_cases" compatibility="7.0.000" expanded="true" height="68" name="Transform Cases" width="90" x="45" y="34">
            <description align="center" color="transparent" colored="false" width="126">Makes everything lowercase</description>
          </operator>
          <operator activated="true" class="text:cut_document" compatibility="7.0.000" expanded="true" height="68" name="Cut Document" width="90" x="179" y="34">
            <parameter key="query_type" value="Regular Expression"/>
            <list key="string_machting_queries"/>
            <list key="regular_expression_queries">
              <parameter key="hashtags" value="(?i)#[0-9a-z_]*"/>
            </list>
            <list key="regular_region_queries"/>
            <list key="xpath_queries"/>
            <list key="namespaces"/>
            <list key="index_queries"/>
            <list key="jsonpath_queries"/>
            <process expanded="true">
              <connect from_port="segment" to_port="document 1"/>
              <portSpacing port="source_segment" spacing="0"/>
              <portSpacing port="sink_document 1" spacing="0"/>
              <portSpacing port="sink_document 2" spacing="0"/>
            </process>
            <description align="center" color="transparent" colored="false" width="126">Gets rid of everything but the hashtags</description>
          </operator>
          <operator activated="true" class="text:combine_documents" compatibility="7.0.000" expanded="true" height="82" name="Combine Documents" width="90" x="313" y="34"/>
          <connect from_port="document" to_op="Transform Cases" to_port="document"/>
          <connect from_op="Transform Cases" from_port="document" to_op="Cut Document" to_port="document"/>
          <connect from_op="Cut Document" from_port="documents" to_op="Combine Documents" to_port="documents 1"/>
          <connect from_op="Combine Documents" from_port="document" to_port="document 1"/>
          <portSpacing port="source_document" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="sink_document 1" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="sink_document 2" spacing="0"/>
        </process>
      </operator>
      <connect from_op="Read CSV" from_port="output" to_op="Process Documents from Data" to_port="example set"/>
      <connect from_op="Process Documents from Data" from_port="example set" to_port="result 1"/>
      <connect from_op="Process Documents from Data" from_port="word list" to_port="result 2"/>
      <portSpacing port="source_input 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 1" spacing="21"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 2" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 3" spacing="0"/>
    </process>
  </operator>
</process>
```